# Facebook integration in android

Tags: android

Friends, I have an error in facebook integration on a button click it always returns NullPointerException,I don't know why? Please suggest me the right result......

Code:

```
package com.ex.softZilla;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.graphics.Color;
import com.ex.softZilla.BaseRequestListener;
import com.ex.softZilla.SessionEvents.AuthListener;
import com.ex.softZilla.SessionEvents.LogoutListener;
import com.ex.softZilla.Facebook.DialogListener;





public class SettingActivity extends Activity{
    final String APP_ID = "172619129456913";
    String bytesSent;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    int count1;
    // List with parameters and their values
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    LoginButton mLoginButton;
    TextView mText;
    Facebook mFacebook;
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertNetwork;
    private Facebook mFb;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private SessionListener mSessionListener = new SessionListener();
    private String[] mPermissions;
    private Activity mActivity;
    Button btn_facebook;
    Button btn_twitter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.more_setting);

    btn_facebook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_More_setting_facebook);
    btn_twitter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_more_setting_twitter);


           btn_facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                alertNetwork = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingActivity.this);
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                   SettingActivity.this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                /* final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
                   connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
                   connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);*/

                /*if( !wifi.isAvailable()||mobile.isAvailable() ){

                       alertNetwork.setTitle("Network Error.");

                        alertNetwork.setMessage("Please check your network connection.");
                        alertNetwork.setNeutralButton("Ok",null);
                                alertNetwork.show();
                                this.onDestroy();
                       }*/

                if (APP_ID == null) {
                    Util.showAlert(SettingActivity.this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be " +
                            "specified before running this example: see Example.java");
                }


                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
                int width = display.getWidth();
                int height = display.getHeight();
                System.out.println("Width:"+width);
                System.out.println("Height:"+height);


                    //  setContentView(R.layout.facebookviewlarge);




                mText = (TextView) SettingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.txt);



                mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

                SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, SettingActivity.this);
                SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
                SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());

                //login class is calling here
               // mLoginButton.init(SettingActivity.this, mFacebook);
                //mLoginButton.

                if (mFb.isSessionValid()) {
                    SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();
                    AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFb);
                    asyncRunner.logout(getApplicationContext(), new LogoutRequestListener());
                } else {
                    mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions,
                                  new LoginDialogListener());
                }   
            }








            /*Intent intent = new Intent(SettingActivity.this,Example.class);
            startActivity(intent);*/


    });
    btn_twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingActivity.this,TwitterViewController.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

    });
}
     class SampleAuthListener implements AuthListener {

            public void onAuthSucceed() {
                mText.setText("You have logged in! ");
                mFacebook.dialog(SettingActivity.this, "feed",  new SampleDialogListener());



            }

            public void onAuthFail(String error) {
                mText.setText("Login Failed: " + error);
            }
        }

        class SampleLogoutListener implements LogoutListener {
            public void onLogoutBegin() {
                mText.setText("Logging out...");
            }

            public void onLogoutFinish() {
                mText.setText("You have logged out! ");

            }
        }

       class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

            public void onComplete(final String response) {
                try {
                    // process the response here: executed in background thread
                    Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
                    JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                    final String name = json.getString("name");

                    // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
                    // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
                    // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
                    // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
                    SettingActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mText.setText("Hello there, " + name + "!");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }


       class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

            public void onComplete(final String response) {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Got response: " + response);
                String message = "<empty>";
                try {
                    JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                    message = json.getString("message");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                final String text = "Your Wall Post: " + message;
                SettingActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mText.setText(text);
                        //postTotalShare();
                    }
                });
            }


        }

      class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                    Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
                    mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());

                }
        }

        }
    class SessionListener implements AuthListener, LogoutListener {

            public void onAuthSucceed() {
                //setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
                SessionStore.save(mFb, getApplicationContext());
            }

            public void onAuthFail(String error) {
            }

            public void onLogoutBegin() {           
            }

            public void onLogoutFinish() {
                SessionStore.clear(getApplicationContext());
                //setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
            }
        }
     public void init(final Activity activity, final Facebook fb) {
            init(activity, fb, new String[] {});
        }

        public void init(final Activity activity, final Facebook fb,
                         final String[] permissions) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mFb = fb;
            mPermissions = permissions;
            mHandler = new Handler();

           // setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
           // setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            //setImageResource(fb.isSessionValid() ?
                             //R.drawable.logout_button : 
                             //R.drawable.login_button);
            //drawableStateChanged();

            SessionEvents.addAuthListener(mSessionListener);
            SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(mSessionListener);

        }

        private final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SessionEvents.onLoginSuccess();
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
            }

            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
            }

            public void onCancel() {
                SessionEvents.onLoginError("Action Canceled");
            }
        }

        private class LogoutRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
            public void onComplete(String response) {
                // callback should be run in the original thread, 
                // not the background thread
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        SessionEvents.onLogoutFinish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
}
```

error:

```
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at com.ex.softZilla.Facebook.startSingleSignOn(Facebook.java:221)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at com.ex.softZilla.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:190)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at com.ex.softZilla.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:114)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at com.ex.softZilla.SettingActivity$1.onClick(SettingActivity.java:127)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-05 15:35:05.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? What is the stacktrace? Please consider trimming that wall of code to only the relevant bit.

Comment: It's probably a very simple issue. You just need to provide the stack trace and maybe trim the code down for us.

Comment: You seem to have two Facebook variables, mFacebook and mFb. Could this be the cause if you're initialising one and using the other still being null?

Comment: thanx harism, but I changed my variables, but still it gives NullPointer Exception..

Comment: I added my error stack please see this and help me out

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You have an init(..) method in which you pass another Activity to this Activity you're sharing with us. Given the nature what Facebook.authorize does I find it a bit weird for not using this -pointer instead. Anyway, first thing I would do is checking that mActivity is not null when calling mFb.authorize(..) from your onClick method. And if it's ok, continuing to Facebook where the exception is raised.

Comment: Ah, and I'm thinking in 'Facebook' here, and their Android SDK. Your use case might differ a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the ever so useful list of good Android libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there/4078596#4078596) perhaps you should use the [Facebook Android API](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) instead (of what looks to be) rolling your own.

Edit: I know... but still.

Anyway I actually looked through your code and I believe that the mPermissions variable is never set to anything and is thus passed in as null, is referenced, and in turn creates your Null pointer exception. It happens when you call this function:

```
mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, new LoginDialogListener());
```

So since mPermissions is null you have a problem. This probably would not have happened if the init function was called but it was commened out:

```
// mLoginButton.init(SettingActivity.this, mFacebook);
```

Maybe the dependencies in the code could be a little smoother; the code is perhaps is not functional enough.

Comment: It is just for facebook login Robert, I need posts for my Android app, which is registered on facebook

Comment: @user621380: Edited to include a potential answer.